# Is it possible to rename tags in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, tags

I am using firefox 17.0.4.
I have quite a large set of bookmarks and have tagged them based on topic.

Recently I found that some of the tags I have marked as UMI; which should have been UML.

Is there any way I can rename my tags in firefox?

Also I have some duplicate tags example: JAVA and Java; which are essentially same. Can I rename all those pages tagged as "Java" now to have the tag "JAVA"?

Is it possible? I am surprised firefox (or any addons) does not provide a way of managing tags :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming tags is very easy, from the menu go to `Bookmarks > Show all bookmarks`, on the left column you can select any tag and edit it by modifying the `name` field.

[image]

To merge two existing tags, you can't simply rename the wrong one with the correct one because Firefox will create two tags with the same name; to do this, you can assing to your bookmarks the correct tag and delete the one that you don't need anymore.
In your example, select all the bookmarks tagged "Java", add "JAVA" to them, then right click on "Java" on the left panel and select `delete`.

And, by the way, you should upgrade your browser to the latest version.

Comment: thanks for the response. The first part of the question helped. For the second part I will wait for someone to provide a more accurate answer.